# RegEx for extracting script tag in Python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I have the following code in Python:

```html
import sys, os, requests, datetime, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import json

def get_html(url):
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.content
        

link = 'https://www.clubx.com.au/products/womanizer-pro?variant=37834367948'
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(link), 'html.parser')

obj = soup.find_all('script')[18]

m = re.search(r"\"variants\":\[(.*?)\]", obj.string)
if m:
    data = json.loads(m.group(1))
    print(data)
```

The print result is:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column
>   495 (char 494)

If i print `obj.string`, i get the result:

> var BOLD = BOLD || {};
>       BOLD.products = BOLD.products || {};
>       BOLD.variant_lookup = BOLD.variant_lookup || {};BOLD.variant_lookup[37834367948]
>   ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368076] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368140] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368204] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368268] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.products["womanizer-pro"] ={"id":10346996748,"title":"Womanizer Pro","handle":"womanizer-pro","description":"\u003cdiv
>   style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003cstrong\u003eThis is a web
>   only offer and excludes all retail stores.
>   \u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003cdiv style=\"text-align:
>   center;\"\u003e\u003cstrong\u003eLimited Time
>   Only\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e \u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cdiv
>   style=\"text-align:
>   center;\"\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eThe
>   world's most advanced clitoral stimulator - The Womanizer® is in the
>   big world surely only a small novelty in the world of sex toys and
>   erotic products the Womanizer® is a real
>   revolution.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eThe revolutionary Womanizer®
>   technology makes it possible to stimulate the clitoris without contact
>   for the first time. An unprecedented experience of lust, crowned with
>   powerful orgasms, can be experienced.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eAn
>   over-stimulation of the clitoris becomes a thing of the past. Orgasms
>   in a previously unexperienced manner and strength - any number of
>   times. \u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003eMany women experience an absolutely
>   new orgasm feeling. The womanizer® technology and mode of operation
>   has nothing to do with a vibrator, the gentlest and yet most powerful
>   stimulator on the world market.\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003eOur
>   delivery includes the womanizer®, a pouch, 1 spare head, 1 USB
>   charging cable and operating
>   manual.\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cspan\u003eSee \u003c/span\u003e\u003ca
>   href=\"https://www.clubx.com.au/blogs/product-reviews/is-the-womanizer-right-for-you\"
>   target=\"_blank\" title=\"Womanizer Product Review\" rel=\"noopener
>   noreferrer\"\u003eour blog post\u003c/a\u003e\u003cspan\u003e to get
>   more information on the Womanizer
>   range.\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003eFeatures\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003cul\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eNon-contact
>   stimulation of the clitoris\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003ePrecisely
>   adjustable control of the intensity (8
>   levels)\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eRechargeable lithium-ion
>   battery\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eTop hygiene treatment by
>   removable head (medical silicone)\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eXL
>   stimulation head for large
>   clitoris\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eGerman top
>   design\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eSplashproof\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eNo
>   habituation effect by new Pleasure Air
>   Technology\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eMade with Swarovski
>   elements\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eMaterial: ABS, phthalate
>   free\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eMaterial stimulation head:
>   hypoallergenic medical
>   silicone\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003eAdvanced rechargeable
>   lithium-ion battery \u003c/li\u003e\n\u003cli\u003e1-year
>   warranty\u003c/li\u003e\n\u003c/ul\u003e","published_at":"2017-04-18T12:47:49","created_at":"2017-04-18T13:19:07","vendor":"Womanizer","type":"Vibrators","tags":["color-lavender","color-leopard","color-magenta","color-mint","color-rose","color-tattoo","color-white","Deluxe","Discounted","For
>   Her","Stimulators","vibrators"],"price":24999,"price_min":24999,"price_max":24999,"price_varies":false,"compare_at_price":30999,"compare_at_price_min":30999,"compare_at_price_max":30999,"compare_at_price_varies":false,"all_variant_ids":[37834367948,37834368076,37834368140,37834368204,37834368268],"variants":[{"id":37834367948,"title":"Black","option1":"Black","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"1725205212","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":2584573542512,"product_id":10346996748,"position":13,"created_at":"2018-05-07T14:01:05+10:00","updated_at":"2018-06-27T16:41:12+10:00","alt":"Womanizer
>   Pro Black - Club
>   X","width":700,"height":700,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/Womanizer-Pro-Black.png?v=1530081672","variant_ids":[37834367948]},"available":true,"name":"Womanizer
>   Pro -
>   Black","public_title":"Black","options":["Black"],"price":24999,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":30999,"inventory_quantity":2,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":"703255205212"},{"id":37834368076,"title":"Magenta","option1":"Magenta","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"1725205229","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":1186546876441,"product_id":10346996748,"position":11,"created_at":"2018-03-13T21:31:40+11:00","updated_at":"2018-05-22T12:06:24+10:00","alt":"Womanizer
>   Pro Magenta - Club
>   X","width":600,"height":600,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/246979818968d47fc7413ea41f7d5158_1459914993_grande_ae47b27d-43fb-4e5c-a85f-b9a35036e0f4.jpg?v=1526954784","variant_ids":[37834368076]},"available":true,"name":"Womanizer
>   Pro -
>   Magenta","public_title":"Magenta","options":["Magenta"],"price":24999,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":30999,"inventory_quantity":1,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":"703255205229"},{"id":37834368140,"title":"Mint","option1":"Mint","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"1725205243","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":1186554576921,"product_id":10346996748,"position":14,"created_at":"2018-03-13T21:34:08+11:00","updated_at":"2018-05-22T12:06:25+10:00","alt":"Womanizer
>   Pro Mint - Club
>   X","width":450,"height":488,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/048d21569da3a18c2c82a335c0e6e17a_1459916999_grande_151de093-60c4-45a1-aace-2ae3bf6cc164.png?v=1526954785","variant_ids":[37834368140]},"available":true,"name":"Womanizer
>   Pro -
>   Mint","public_title":"Mint","options":["Mint"],"price":24999,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":30999,"inventory_quantity":6,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":"703255205243"},{"id":37834368204,"title":"Rose","option1":"Rose","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"172205250","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":1186542157849,"product_id":10346996748,"position":10,"created_at":"2018-03-13T21:30:24+11:00","updated_at":"2018-05-22T12:06:23+10:00","alt":"Womanizer
>   Pro Rose - Club
>   X","width":600,"height":600,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/7b2cc1561424b59f315dc9832fd4c834_1460014564_grande_e8738aaa-5a85-4f83-a384-fd1b4e1f0b89.jpg?v=1526954783","variant_ids":[37834368204]},"available":true,"name":"Womanizer
>   Pro -
>   Rose","public_title":"Rose","options":["Rose"],"price":24999,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":30999,"inventory_quantity":1,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":"703255205250"},{"id":37834368268,"title":"White","option1":"White","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"1725205236","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":{"id":1186555330585,"product_id":10346996748,"position":15,"created_at":"2018-03-13T21:34:23+11:00","updated_at":"2018-05-22T12:06:26+10:00","alt":"Womanizer
>   Pro White - Club
>   X","width":600,"height":600,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/7892c10587439f32cc3cec90a960b059_1459918683_grande_bf23ffca-e3c1-498a-b5a2-70da92c22591.jpg?v=1526954786","variant_ids":[37834368268]},"available":true,"name":"Womanizer
>   Pro -
>   White","public_title":"White","options":["White"],"price":24999,"weight":0,"compare_at_price":30999,"inventory_quantity":5,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":"703255205236"}],"available":false,"images":["//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/e003edb648fd35ff2fa272881176b81b_1460018691.jpg?v=1526954778","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/womanizer-pro-purple_1.png?v=1526954779","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/womanizer-pro-gold.png?v=1526954779","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/8f66fcbb15839f44872691a6f6baa8e1_1459914986.jpg?v=1526954780","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/fa5f253c5726b7bfe1eee169eb5df3cc_1459916829.png?v=1526954781","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/ace7842e9a0769b9b12d393f14635d85_1459919036.jpg?v=1526954781","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/d00d67d74f47e3c8e9414235fa3ebf3b_1460022454.png?v=1526954782","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/6557e39ded6ea133945aff0d0a2a7a77_1459917861.jpg?v=1526954782","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/5778230f1e1ea39ac8f7f6b9dc1bb623_1459917950_grande_71c126da-c86c-4593-a154-27c2e0dbf133.jpg?v=1528092578","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/7b2cc1561424b59f315dc9832fd4c834_1460014564_grande_e8738aaa-5a85-4f83-a384-fd1b4e1f0b89.jpg?v=1526954783","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/246979818968d47fc7413ea41f7d5158_1459914993_grande_ae47b27d-43fb-4e5c-a85f-b9a35036e0f4.jpg?v=1526954784","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/e8e5cd8a56d792956774acdfb49060b2_1459914573_grande_5fc1db06-b57a-49b1-8461-f4a8f1fc3f9c.jpg?v=1530081671","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/Womanizer-Pro-Black.png?v=1530081672","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/048d21569da3a18c2c82a335c0e6e17a_1459916999_grande_151de093-60c4-45a1-aace-2ae3bf6cc164.png?v=1526954785","//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/7892c10587439f32cc3cec90a960b059_1459918683_grande_bf23ffca-e3c1-498a-b5a2-70da92c22591.jpg?v=1526954786"],"featured_image":"//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0682/0289/products/e003edb648fd35ff2fa272881176b81b_1460018691.jpg?v=1526954778","options":["Color"],"url":"/products/womanizer-pro"}

I need to exstract sku, title from `variants`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex pattern `r"\"variants\":\[(.*?)\]"`

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

s = """<script>var BOLD = BOLD || {};
    BOLD.products = BOLD.products || {};
    BOLD.variant_lookup = BOLD.variant_lookup || {};BOLD.variant_lookup[31066737740] ="womanizer";BOLD.variant_lookup[31066737804] ="womanizer";BOLD.variant_lookup[31066737868] ="womanizer";BOLD.variant_lookup[31066737996] ="womanizer";BOLD.variant_lookup[1509908217881] ="womanizer";BOLD.products["womanizer"] ={"id":8993669708,"title":"Womanizer","variants":[{"id":37834367948,"title":"Black","option1":"Black","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"1725205212"}]}
    </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
src = soup.find("script")
m = re.search(r"\"variants\":\[(.*?)\]", src.string)
if m:
    data = json.loads(m.group(1))
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'sku': u'1725205212', u'title': u'Black', u'id': 37834367948L, u'option2': None, u'option3': None, u'option1': u'Black'}
```

Comment: It`s working when 's' is a string type. But in my case i have <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> for 's'.
so Error has occured: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 495 (char 494)

Comment: My code has following structure:

def get_html(url):
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.content
        

link = 'https://www.clubx.com.au/products/womanizer-pro?variant=37834367948'
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(link), 'html.parser')

obj = soup.find_all('script')[18]

m = re.search(r"\"variants\":\[(.*?)\]", obj.string)
if m:
    data = json.loads(m.group(1))
    print(data)

Comment: What does `obj.string` print ?

Comment: it prints content

Comment: Like this: 'var BOLD = BOLD || {};
    BOLD.products = BOLD.products || {};
    BOLD.variant_lookup = BOLD.variant_lookup || {};BOLD.variant_lookup[37834367948] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368076] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368140] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368204] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.variant_lookup[37834368268] ="womanizer-pro";BOLD.products["womanizer-pro"] ={"id":10346996748,"title":"Womanizer Pro","handle":"womanizer-pro","description":"\u003cdiv style=\"text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e'.

Comment: Add it in your question.

Comment: I have refresh question

Comment: Do you have a `;` at the end of the string?

Comment: There is no ';' at the end.